Best place to add DC biasing
I'm working on a circuit where I have a CS4344 audio DAC feeding into a LM324 inverting amplifier that uses 1.2v as a reference voltage.
I'm staring with the example circuit shown in the CS4344 datasheet:
(https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS4344-45-48_F2.pdf)

Since I lose the DC bias after the 3.3uF cap I believe need to add it back or else I'll get clipping since most of that signal is below my opamp's 1.2V Vref. (And I'm seing this clipping after the opamp). I plan on using a resistor divider to add a 1.2V bias back. My question is, should I place the divider on the right side of the 470ohm resistor or simply use the 10k pulldown as part of the divider and add a pullup at that node?
I'm not exactly sure what the 10k and 470Ohm resistors are for in the example above.
Thanks!
-Adam

The DAC can directly drive a line level input. Why there needs to be an op-amp, and why of all possible audio op-amps, there is a barely acceptable LM324?

I'm replicating a classic arcade PCB using an FPGA and the opamp is so I can match the OEM voltage levels that the original sound amp will expect.

All those ground symbols in the "Note*" box could be a +1.2V node, if that's the bias offset you require. It would have to be low impedance, though, to avoid cross-talk and distortion. A simple voltage follower to provide $V_{REF}=+1.2V$ would suffice.

If you want to keep the DC offset don't block it with a capacitor.
